# How to use Element Selector with Class Selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have Simple Table with some TDs having Class as 'PLUS' and Some TDs with class 'MINUS'.

I am implementing the Collapse all and Expand All functionality using jquery.

On click of Expand All, I want to replace 'PLUS' class with 'MINUS' of only TDs who has 'PLUS' class.

and on click of Collapse All, replace 'MINUS' class with 'PLUS'

I am facing problem for finding all TDs with plus class and iterate through all of them to replace class

Any Suggestions please?

Comment: We definitely require your code.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Please post your HTML and the JS you have attempted to write yourself.

Comment: Code is better than 1000 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to iterate, jQuery will do this for you very conveniently.

It's not very clear from the question what exactly you want to do, but you can:

- Switch `.plus` to `.minus` with

  ```
  $(".plus").toggleClass("plus minus")
  ```
- Toggle `.plus` and `.minus` on all elements that have either with

  ```
  $(".plus, .minus").toggleClass("plus minus")
  ```

Comment: toggleClass is best method in scenario, it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A selector for an element with a class is `{tag}.{class}` http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm

```
// When clicked, replace all td.plus with td.minus
$('td.plus').click(function(){
    $('td.plus').toggleClass('plus minus')
});
```

Comment: I used your code it worked